# AWS IAM: Policy to allow adding anyone to a group except oneself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there a way to restrict iam:AddUserToGroup by which user is being added? I would like to build a policy that allows adding any user to a group except for the requester not being allowed to add himself. I am able to limit other actions by limiting the requester as an available resource, but in this case the resource is the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think it's possible to restrict who a user can add to a group when attempting to do so from the AWS console. If you used some other tool, such as Lambda, to modify group membership then you could do this.

IAM permissions can go as far as actions for services and resources but not to the parameters of those actions. Would be cool if they did. :)

For instance the action `AddUserToGroup` can be allowed or restricted per policy. Same with the group resource that the action would be applied to. So You could go as far as restricting or allowing access to the `AddUserToGroup` action on a specific resource (group) but IAM does not allow you to base the policy condition on a parameter of an action.

In this case, the parameter `UserName` on the `AddUserToGroup` action.

Comment: I ended up using a lambda function to automatically remove a user from a group whenever AddUserToGroup is called to add oneself to a group. I found this AWS security blog post to be very helpful for defining the elements needed to set this up: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-revoke-unintended-iam-access-with-amazon-cloudwatch-events/

Answer (score 0):

In combination with an execution role and permissions defined in the blog post mentioned in the comment on byumark's answer, I used this simple lambda function to auto-remediate the kind of action I was looking to prevent:

```
'use strict';

var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var iam = new aws.IAM();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Log the incoming Amazon CloudWatch Events event     
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

     // If the caller is not an IAM user, do nothing
     if (event.detail.userIdentity.type != 'IAMUser') {
         context.done();
     } else {
        var userName = event.detail.userIdentity.userName;

        // If the user is adding herself to a group
        if (event.detail.eventName === "AddUserToGroup" &&
                event.detail.requestParameters.userName === userName) {

            // Remove the user from that group
            var groupName = event.detail.requestParameters.groupName;
            console.log('User adding self to group detected. Removing user',
                            userName, 'from group', groupName);

            var params = {
                GroupName: groupName, 
                UserName: userName
            };
            iam.removeUserFromGroup(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
     }
  }
```